# Redirect if userid is not found in a database table

Tags: user, jdatabase, redirect, id

When users login, I am trying to push them to fill their 3rd party component's Profile form properly.

When they filled the form their user id is added to the "#__rbid_users" table (user id is same as the Joomla user id).

This is what I made but there is something wrong - the code is not matching.

```
<?php 
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select($db->quoteName(array('userid')))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__rbid_users'));
    $rbiduser = $db->loadObjectList();
if (in_array(joomlausers->id, $rbiduser->userid))
{

}
else
{
  echo '<html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="url=profile" />
        </head>
        <body>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that you're using `joomlausers->id` which doesn't look correct. It should be `$joomlausers->id` (with a `$` at the beginning).

Secondly, `loadObjectList()` returns an indexed array of PHP objects, so I don't believe `in_array` will work with this.

Instead, I'd suggest using `$db->loadColumn()`, which will return an array of all `userid`'s, like so:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select($db->quoteName('userid'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__rbid_users'));
$db->setQuery($query);

$array = $db->loadColumn();

if (in_array($joomlausers->id, $array, true))
{
    // Id exists
}
else
{
    JFactory::getApplication()->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_something&view=something'));
}
```

Note, do not start trying to inject custom metas anywhere as you've done in your current code. Instead use Joomla's redirect method as shown above.

Hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately it is not working. Even if id is exist still redirecting to the url

Comment: Is `$joomlausers` an instance of the `JUser` object? How are you defining this?

Comment: It is my bad. Sorry, you are right. I had to change `$joomlausers` to `$user->id` and add `$user = JFactory::getUser();` to the top

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is very direct to filter the result set when sql is perfectly qualified to do such logic.

As Lodder corrected, you also need to use `setQuery()`, fix your missing `$`, adjust your result set generating method call, and improve your redirect technique.

I've included some helpful diagnostic lines to help you to understand the query that is being generated and if there are any syntax errors, they will be displayed (so long as you don't run the redirect portion of your script).

After running my script, you may discover that:

1. you have an sql error (for instance `userid` is not the same as `user_id`)
2. you don't actually have the `$joomlausers->id` value that you think you have
3. ...or something else that you haven't posted in your question is causing trouble.

Untested Snippet:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$user = JFactory::getUser();

if ($user->guest) {
    $app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_something&view=something'));
}

try {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select("COUNT(1)")
                ->from("#__rbid_users")
                ->where("userid = " . (int)$user->id);

    $app->enqueueMessage($query->dump(), 'info');
    //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - use only during debuggin

    $db->setQuery($query);
    if (!$db->loadResult()) {  // loadResult() should return either 0 or 1
        // no error and no count, execute redirect
        $app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_something&view=something'));
    } else {
        // id matched
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $app->enqueueMessage("Query Syntax Error: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');
    //                 use only during debugging -^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

It is important that I state that you must never show the exact query or error messages to the public as a matter of site security!

To be clear, the `enqueueMessage()` calls are not required, they are just to assist your debugging.

Comment: You and @Lodder is right about it. Instead of `$joomlausers` i had to `$user->id` and add `$user = JFactory::getUser();` to the top. Now it is working. Thank you for warning.